# Menu toggle different animation on every second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've created a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/d9wf1s44/

When I click the hamburger menu, the breadcrumbs toggles away to right, and after that the function executes which shows the menu.

```
        $menu_toggle.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            breadcrumbs_bar.toggle('slide', {direction:'right'}, 800, function(){
                $navigation.fadeToggle(600);
            });
        });
```

Now the issue is that when I click again, naturally, the same thing will happen, the breadcrumb will toggle and menu will fade out. It's just that I'd like first the menu to fade out, and then the menu to toggle in. How can I do that? `animate` is used for css manipulation and I tried doing everything with css transitions and delay, but couldn't achieve the nice result like here, I like the toggle animation that the breadcrumbs has, so that's why I'm using toggle (also the breadcrumbs get display none, so the menu is right next to the icon).

How can I control what happens on second click? How to separate this?

Comment: Move e.preventDefault(); to the end of the click function - then i'd look at promises for making sure one fade has finished before the next one starts - Google "JQuery promise done"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make alternate animation for close the menu

after you toggle class "open", you have to do as below :

```
if($(this).hasClass('open')){ //open function
     breadcrumbs_bar.toggle('slide', {direction:'right'}, 800, function(){
         $navigation.fadeIn(600);
     });
}else{
     $navigation.fadeOut(600, function(){
         breadcrumbs_bar.toggle('slide', {direction:'right'}, 800)
     });
}
```

you can check my jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/euds0n6x/

Comment: This is it. I just did something like this, but I added a class to header, and then checked if header has class `opened` and then reversed the toggle, but your way is more efficient! Thanks! :)